# How to pass both file (uploaded) and dict params to POST request in FAST API?

Tags: python, python-requests, request, fastapi

Specifically, I want the example below to work:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import UploadFile

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/check")
def foo(grid: dict, file: UploadFile):
    return {"len_grid": len(grid), "filename": file.filename}
```

Currently, while trying to create a POST request passing any valid dict to `grid` parameter and upload some `file`, FAST API raises the error:

```
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "grid"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
      "type": "type_error.dict"
    }
  ]
}
```

At the same time, if I use only one of these parameters inside the  function, it works well.

I am calling (testing) my API this way:

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/check'
file = {'file': open('ny_pollution_events.csv', 'rb')}
payload = {"grid": {"name": "Alex", "age": 15}}
resp = requests.post(url=url, data=payload, files=file)
print(resp.json())
```

as well as via in-built Swagger UI.

[image: Swagger UI]

Comment: Can you share the cURL request or so by which you are invoking the API?

Comment: just updated my question with that info

Comment: You can't. Files are passed as multipart/form-data which does not match the required application/json content-type; if you need additional data, use `Form` fields (which can contain serialized JSON if necessary, which can be automagically decoded with a Pydantic JSON type) or base64 encode the file contents and submit it as part of the JSON body.

Comment: But, here is another related question. Say, instead of 'dict' parameter I declare some 'list' type parameter without specifying Query(). As per docs, such param would be treated as Body (not a Query) parameter, and as far as I understand should be encoded using application/json content-type.  I tried to create such (along with UploadFile param), and then made a request, using JSON in payload and it still works. So, why I still have UploadFile param and another 'list' type param that is encoded as JSON and function works? Or list type params are not encoded as JSONs?

Comment: @MatsLindh
Here is what I mean. 
Function (https://ibb.co/qCM4JB3)
API calling (https://ibb.co/Lg773Qn)
Successful response: (https://ibb.co/cQ5b7L0).

Comment: It's because of a peculiarity of how most web frameworks (including Starlette/FastAPI) handles the same parameter name being repeated in POST requests, if you submit `foo=1&foo=2&foo=3` and type the parameter as being a List, you'll get a list those strings back. So you're not sending JSON, you're sending the same regular form-data parameter two times (`features_list=string1`, `features_list=string2`) and three times (`events_list=a`, `events_list=b`, `events_list=c`). Some languages/frameworks uses `foo[key]` to represent dicts in the same way (PHP, some Java frameworks, etc.)

Comment: So you're not sending JSON, you're relying on the structure of how a specific set of form-data parameters are handled. Your `grid` argument to `requests` ends up being sent as `grid=name` and `grid=age`, since that's what the iterator returns when iterating over the dict. BTW: Next time, include your additional code in your question (your initial question was perfectly asked to include copy-pastable code); retyping the code from the images were a PITA :-)

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks a lot. Now, it is clear to me. Thank you for your time.